# Get from array of objects, objects that include specific key

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, key

I would like to obtain from All_reports the objects that include the key: comentarioAdmin. Now I'm obtaining in All_reports, all the reports, but I just want the reports that include the key comentarioAdmin. Thank you!

```
getReports() {
    this.Service.getReportes().subscribe((data) => {
      this.All_reports = data;

      console.log('respuesta de alumno->' + this.All_reports);
    });
  }
```

This is how I have my array of objects, some of them include comentarioAdmin and others don't:

```
[
.
.
.

{
        "_id": "5ee1b1f04e9bfe060050cacf",
        "nombre": "Mario",
        "apellido": "López No-Gattelll",
        "correo": "covid19@gov.mx",
        "direccion": "Varsovia 54, Juárez, 06600 Cuauhtemoc, CDMX",
        "referencia": "",
        "tipoPersona": "Otro",
        "comentario": "Hay una fuga a la mitad de la calle.",
        "numeroReporte": 2,
        "__v": 0,
        "comentarioAdmin": "PRUEBA"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ee1c247634773d6e00e44d4",
        "nombre": "Fabián",
        "apellido": "Oropeza Oropeza",
        "correo": "fabo2o@aol.com",
        "direccion": "Calle 10 de febrero 56 MH, CDMX",
        "referencia": "Es mi casa",
        "tipoPersona": "Otro",
        "comentario": "Justo en rente de mi casa hay una fuga y mi carro se moja cuando salgo.",
        "numeroReporte": 1,
        "__v": 0,
    },
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. Try the following

```js
var input = [{
    "comentario": "Hay una fuga a la mitad de la calle.",
    "numeroReporte": 2,
    "__v": 0,
    "comentarioAdmin": "PRUEBA"
  },
  {
    "referencia": "Es mi casa",
    "tipoPersona": "Otro",
    "comentario": "Justo en rente de mi casa hay una fuga y mi carro se moja cuando salgo.",
    "numeroReporte": 1,
    "__v": 0,
  }
];


var output = input.filter(item => {
  if (item.comentarioAdmin) {
    return item;
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Typescript:

```js
getReports() {
  this.Service.getReportes().subscribe((data) => {
    this.All_reports = data.filter(item => {
      if (item.comentarioAdmin) {
        return item;
      }
    });
    console.log('respuesta de alumno->' + this.All_reports);
  });
}
```